# window.print on a long React DOM captures only one page

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-dom

I have a react component which renders markdown, and can be multi page. 
When component is rendered in the browser, the scrolling in the component works fine.

But when I call window.print or ctrl + P on the page, the preview captrues only one page. Its not scrolling and not splitting the content into multiple pages.

Can somebody please suggest how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Answering this hoping it will be useful to somebody else.

The react renders a virtual dom, rendering only the content of view port. Not full component. And print preview was getting only the content of view port.

I solved the issue by rendering everything to and IFrame and then printing the the IFrame.

Comment: Some React-y libraries handle the iFrame, but style considerations remain e.g., @media print, scrolling, and display. This [thread](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/issues/54) & patterns below have been helpful
`
@media print {
  html, body {
    height: initial !important;
    overflow: initial !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}

@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 20mm;
}
`

`
@media all {
  .page-break {
     display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  .page-break {
      display: block;
      page-break-before: auto;
    }
}
`